# Jetty with owne JAAS

Tags: jakarta-ee, jetty, jetty-9

I implement a JAAS LoginModule, using the artifact

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
<version>${jetty.version}</version>
```

The implementation of LoginModule extends the class `AbstractLoginModule` as recommended in Jetty Documentation. If I use `<scope>provided</scope>` to declare dependency of `jetty-util` then I get the exception

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/security/Credential` with the cause `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Credential`.

But if I remove the `<scope>`-Tag to include it in Classpath as runtime, then I get the exception

`javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/realm/ClassRealm) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/eclipse/jetty/util/security/Credential"`

If I use the default JAAS-Implementation `PropertyFileLoginModule` everything just works out-of-the-box. Of course I have not to declare the dependency of this artifact. It is included in jetty maven plugin.

All the exceptions happen when I run the jetty:run-Plugin in maven.

My JAAS-Implementation is separated in a artifact, my web Project is separated in an other artifact, based on the artifact `test-jaas-webapp` provided by jetty in github.

How can I use my own JASS-Implementation in conjunction with Jetty Maven plugin?

Environment: Jetty 9.2.x, Java 1.8_u111, Maven 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, After some try-and-error I had found to deal with Classloader in manner of maven Project. 
First JAAS Artifact:

- JAAS implementation must be in a separated artifact.
- This artifact can use jetty-util as dependency, but just in scope provided.
- This artifact must be loaded as an module of jetty server. One way to do it is, put the jar of the artifact in lib/ext and use option `--module=ext` by starting up jetty (More about classpath: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/startup-classpath.html)

Now the webapp can use this implementation of JAAS. The webapp must not declare the implementation of JAAS in its dependency (POM-File). Even though it can use the customized JAAS implementation before by configuration as in Jetty Doc:
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jaas-support.html

Comment: PS: Some more information about Classloader:

* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720149/the-secureclassloaders-purpose
* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureClassLoader.html